# Android Studio sdkmanager and tools folder is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

Good day,
I reinstalled Android Studio 2-3 times and still I am unable to get the tools folder created in my sdk folder.
I manually tried downloading but the following error is popping up:
[Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/665Xh.png)

Following are my configuration

[SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MR5i.png)
[SDK Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKBXq.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio

1. Uninstall Android SDK Command-line Tools under the SDK Tools tab. Close Android Studio
2. In your sdk folder delete or rename cmdline-tools folder and tools folder Open Android Studio
3. In SDK Manager see if Command-line is still checkmarked or partially marked uninstall it again. If not then install the latest
   one, don't install older one. Close Android Studio Open CMD
4. Navigate to %sdk folder%\cmdline-tools\bin\
5. Run sdkmanager --licenses
   Accept them

NOTE : flutter doctor will still show error but should run fine